# Make a column nullable in Ingres

Tags: database, nullable, ddl, alter, ingres

I would like to **make a column nullable in Ingres Database**, but I couldn't find the statement, or any tool that allow me to do this.

Anyone can help me?

---

Ingres Version: 9.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's create a table with a NOT NULL field:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( field_1 CHAR(10) NOT NULL )
```

In order to convert that field so it allows NULL values you need this:

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN field_1 char(10) NULL
```

For reference the Actian Ingres SQL manual can be found here:
[Actian Ingres 2006 SQL Reference Guide](http://downloads.actian.com/download/sql.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ALTER TABLE](http://docs.actian.com/?aspectfilter=#b18432t18986n/s-1/s2682/s2703/s2703b114658/s2703b114702/s2703b114703).  Also, use the [Ingres forums](http://community.actian.com/forum/) instead of Stack Overflow.